# Setting up arduino with HTerm - data display problems

Tags: arduino

I am trying to configure my Arduino Wi-Fi module (RN-XV) with HTerm. However, when i connect it, it starts giving me strange output to the Recieved Data box. Squares and some characters, but nothing that i could read or use. What might be the problem?

(Problem shouldnt be anything about the values i set before connecting, because those settings worked with other guy)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the com port speed is set wrong
According to the manual [Manual](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/WiFly-RN-UM.pdf)
9600 baudrate, 8 bits, No Parity, 1 stop bit, and hardware flow control disabled is the default setup.
If this does not work try different com speeds.